# urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found , code runs correctly in my local machine but gives 404 error in Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, python, aws

```
  File "Humo.py", line 236, in <module>
    bot.polling()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 196, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(none_stop, interval, timeout)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 220, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 103, in raise_exceptions
    six.reraise(self.exc_info[0], self.exc_info[1], self.exc_info[2])
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 703, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 54, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "Humo.py", line 210, in send_welcome
    engine='python')
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 676, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 431, in _read
    filepath_or_buffer, encoding, compression
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 172, in get_filepath_or_buffer
    req = urlopen(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 141, in urlopen
    return urllib.request.urlopen(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 532, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 642, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 570, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

am trying to deploy a bot on AWS using ubuntu, the thing is the code runs ok on my machine but not ubuntu , maybe it is a dependency problem but am not sure or security thing, am trying to access this URL. I dont want to the reuqirements.txt as it rise errors even when I delete (pywin).

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/04-20-2020.csv

DIG resutls for raw.githubusercontent.com :-

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.11-Ubuntu <<>> raw.githubusercontent.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 27399
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;raw.githubusercontent.com.     IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
raw.githubusercontent.com. 30   IN      CNAME   github.map.fastly.net.
github.map.fastly.net.  29      IN      A       151.101.248.133

;; Query time: 22 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Tue Apr 21 04:26:48 UTC 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 105
```

Comment: Hi! It seems to me like a DNS issue.  Can you make sure that you can resolv the host `raw.githubusercontent.com`, using the command `ping` or `dig` (if installed), and post back the results?

Comment: ping results : -
--- github.map.fastly.net ping statistics ---
69 packets transmitted, 69 received, 0% packet loss, time 68105ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 10.738/10.823/12.301/0.216 ms

see the post for dig results: -

all done in the ubuntu

Comment: So, not a DNS issue, can you please try to install the `dos2unix` package and run it against your python script? `dos2unix script.py`.  The error being issued is related to the URL not being found (error 404), so it may be some odd character on the URL.

Comment: am kind of new sorrry, but i get this output
```
dos2unix: converting file Humo.py to Unix format...
```

Comment: if i do python3 script.py after dos2unix , i get same error
and btw , am accessing the csv file this way
data = pd.read_csv(url)
that why I think am missing some dependency

Comment: fboacentura, THANK YOU SO MUCH, talking to you made me realize that i was accessing it wrong
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/{}.csv
where {} are datetime.today().strftime('%m-%d-%Y')